# How do you disable IPv4 on 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to disable IPv4 on a system I'm working on to check how a project interacts over purely IPv6. Does anyone know the following:

- How to disable IPv4 (and verify that it is indeed disabled)
- Check that IPv6 is enabled

Comment: You can disable it in NM.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for responding, is it possible to do via cmd line?

Comment: @sreya sure. NM used files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Comment: @Rinzwind that directory is empty unfortunately

Comment: I have always disabled IPv6 via the grub command line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"`. I do not know, nor have I tested, if the other way around also works, i.e. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv4.disable=1"`

Comment: Dough is pretty close - that passes arguments to kernel. But more practical way to use those commands is via /etc/sysctl.conf file. I'd post an answer but I'm on phone. Will do so once i get the chance

Comment: @Serg hi wanted to see if you were still cool posting an answer. I think based on context clues I can probably figure it out, but is there a good way to verify that you have ipv6 or ipv4 disabled?

Comment: @sreya sure, I can do that, just need to find time.